# capability of `posix_spawn`

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix

I'm writing a small program which is somewhat a server that spawns its client programs (locally, not over the network) and do interesting things between them. While my primary OS in use is Linux, I expect this to run on other OSes including Windows. There is `fork` and `exec` which does the job, but when I port the program to Windows via cygwin, I don't want that crappy `fork` implemented in cygwin to kick in, which actually calls `CreateProcess` and copies the current process's memory area to the new process using `setjmp`/`longjmp` with shared memory mutexes, all of this in order to be replaced with another program (`exec`). While reading the FAQ page of cygwin I discovered `spawn.h` and its `posix_spawn`, which basically looks like `CreatePorcess(Ex)` in windows. It seems like a new feature (... I mean not one of the original UNIX system functions), so I have some questions upon it.

1. Is it implemented well, widely? (I saw some posts on the internet that it is not defined under his/her system.)
2. Can I expect any performance improvement or deterioration by using `posix_spawn` instead of `fork`/`exec` in Linux?
3. Why is `posix_spawn` less known and less used than `fork`/`exec` although being standard since 1999?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`posix_spawn` is *not* widely implemented, but you should use it when you can anyway.

- If a platform lacks it, it's always easy to use a drop-in replacement that just does fork-and-exec.
- If a "native"/optimal implementation is available (either as part of the system, or a drop-in platform-specific one), it will make a big difference for systems where `fork` is expensive, and even more of a difference for systems that can't do `fork` at all (MMU-less systems, Windows without something like cygwin, etc.).
- Even on systems where `fork` is native and "fast", it can still be rather slow if the parent has lots of virtual mappings, and it's mildly slower than an optimal `posix_spawn` even for a small parent. See this Twitter thread for some findings: https://twitter.com/RichFelker/status/602313644026761216

As to why it's not more widely used/implemented, it's probably a mix of not being widely known, and the rather klunky, gratuitously object-oriented API design.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is it implemented well, widely? (I saw some posts on the internet that it is not defined under his/her system.)

The advanced realtime XSI Option Group is optional, so you can conform to POSIX, while not implementing it. But for GNU/Linux, you can count on having it available nowadays.

> 2. Can I expect any performance improvement or deterioration by using posix_spawn instead of fork/exec in Linux?

Probably yes, for big processes [quite some time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5153712/1257035) could be spent copying page tables only to be discarded at `exec` time. Implementations of `posix_spawn` like musl's or glibc's use [`vfork(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html) (or [`clone(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) directly) when possible in order to avoid this. For systems like cygwin, `fork` is [emulated](https://github.com/openunix/cygwin/blob/master/winsup/cygwin/fork.cc#L666) at a considerable cost and `posix_spawn` greatly reduces overhead.

> 3. Why is posix_spawn less known and less used than fork/exec although being standard since 1999?

Inertia, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Linux man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_spawn.3.html) it appeared in glibc version 2.2 which was released in 2000, and that implementation conforms to POSIX.1-2001 and POSIX.1-2008. I'd expect it to be supported on at least any platform that uses at least this glibc version, as its behaviour can at least be emulated with `fork` + `exec` on those platforms.

On Linux you might expect slight performance improvements over `fork`/`exec` if `vfork` is used instead of `fork`:

> The child process is created using vfork(2) instead of fork(2) when either of the following is true:
>
> - the spawn-flags element of the attributes object pointed to by attrp contains the GNU-specific flag POSIX_SPAWN_USEVFORK; or
> - file_actions  is  NULL  and  the spawn-flags element of the attributes object pointed to by attrp does not contain POSIX_SPAWN_SETSIGMASK, POSIX_SPAWN_SETSIGDEF, POSIX_SPAWN_SETSCHEDPARAM,
>           POSIX_SPAWN_SETSCHEDULER, POSIX_SPAWN_SETPGROUP, or POSIX_SPAWN_RESETIDS.
>
> In other words, vfork(2) is used if the caller requests it, or if there is no cleanup expected in the child before it exec(3)s the requested file.