# Redis Vector Similarity Search persistence

Tags: redis, vector-search

I'm building a vector similarity search product and planning to use [Redis Vector Similary search](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/search/vectors/) solution as the vector database.

Naturally I would like to save the data I index into Redis since we might be using paid OpenAI embeddings for example and I want to preserve this data.

So I have been reading about [Redis persistence](https://redis.io/docs/management/persistence/) but I'm still not sure what approach exactly to use if I want to persist mostly vector data.

What is the best approach in terms of space and speed for this particular application of Redis?

Answer (score 1):

it depends on your specifics.
Basically, RDB does not impact performance much since the main process forks a child process which does all the writing, and the backup files are compact, but you can lose minutes of your data.
AOF is definitely more durable, though AOF files are usually bigger, and the AOF can be slower.

These topics may be useful to consider:
[Is RDB preferable over AOF if datasize if large in Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69390000/is-rdb-preferable-over-aof-if-datasize-if-large-in-redis)
[How Redis RDB persistance actually works behind the scene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46599712/how-redis-rdb-persistance-actually-works-behind-the-scene)