# Can death gtests be sped up on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, googletest

Here is the death test on Linux:

```cpp
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <cassert>

void foo()
{
    assert(false);
}

TEST(MyTestDeathTest, MyTest)
{
    ASSERT_DEATH(foo(), "");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);

    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Here is the output:

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from MyTestDeathTest
[ RUN      ] MyTestDeathTest.MyTest

gtest.cpp:****:: Death tests use fork(), which is unsafe particularly in a threaded context. For this test, Google Test couldn't detect the number of threads.

[       OK ] MyTestDeathTest.MyTest (210 ms)
[----------] 1 test from MyTestDeathTest (210 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (210 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

If I comment out `assert(false)` the test fails with `failed to die`, but takes only 2 ms.

So I have only two death tests in my suite, but it gives me 0.5 second slowdown. Can it be helped?

Comment: Do you run the release/optimized build?

Comment: No it's a debug build -O1.

Comment: Is half a second to run your unit tests really the end of the world?

Comment: ¿Perhaps have crash dump generation enabled? And / or additional crash reporting facilities, such as apport on ubuntu.

Comment: @AlanBirtles, well, what if I want to write more death unit gtests?

Comment: @user7860670, thank you for the idea! I will investigate.

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731531/faster-forking-of-large-processes-on-linux  If I had this problem I'd probably try to reimplement this gtest death test with function mentioned in the linked post. But probably this is not the solution you are looking for - too troublesome...